# How to use a specific satellite constellation for positioning in Android?

Tags: android, gps

Is there a way to use just a specific constellation set in Android? As far as I know the smartphone would query all available constellations & somehow pick the best one to be used further by other apps that show user location.

In my specific case, I want to get data from a specific constellation set, say GLONAS or GPS. Is that possible? (Again, as far as I know there are ways to check if the data being used is from a specific constellation, but I want the other way around, where I'm only using the data from a specific constellation?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I was researching if it was possible to do so, and found the descrption of the method/API on this page:

https://barbeau.medium.com/gnss-interrupted-the-hidden-android-setting-you-need-to-know-d812d28a3821

Qoute:

> Device with Android 7.0 and higher support an official API for pseudorange measurements and navigation messages, which allows developers to calculate positions within apps. Previously, all apps were limited to using positions calculated by the GNSS hardware, which was a black box. The European Union GNSS Agency (GSA) has even produced a how-to manual describing the technical process of using raw measurement data. Google has also open-sourced a set of tools to process and visualize measurements.